# Percentage and Decimals

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert a varchar to a percentage with a decimal.  For example, my report is returning 13590 as a result for a rate, which I would like to have a result of 13.590%.  I can't seem to get this to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What SQL vendor? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: convert (varchar(40),[rate]/1000)+ ' %' as "Rate"

Comment: Please update your current question with this information for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arithmetic operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html) inside your query, e.g.
`SELECT (report / 100) as rate FROM MyTable;`.

If the `%` is needed, look at the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution, and will drop trailing zeros

```
SELECT cast(cast(columnA as float) / cast(1000 as float) as varchar(20)) + '%'
```